# Test if a created object is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, testing, null

I am using this code

```
    if (managedObject == nil) {
        NSLog(@"foooo");
    }
```

to test if the created managedObject is nil or not. But I can never print this Fooooo.
Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. It just means that the `managedObject` you created was always non-nil ! If you want us to comment more, you need to post more code before that line.

Comment: show some more code. what is managedObject. and what r u doing with this?

Comment: You if statement is valid, you will have to tell us more if we are going to be able to help you.

Comment: If you can't print that foooo, it's because your object is not nil... I don't see the problem.

Comment: that just implies that `managedObject` is always set to something

Answer (score 13, accepted):

exactly the same with comparing with nil like this

```
if (!managedObject) {
    NSLog(@"foooo");
}
```

Comment: That's exactly the same with comparing with `nil`. I prefer `!managedObject` just like you, though.

Comment: i dont know y those people downvote to me.if anyone downvoting somewhere please put the reason for it.ha!

Comment: Downvoted because your answer doesn't answer the question and is the same thing.  The original question asked what they were doing wrong and the first comment on the question pretty much answered it.

Comment: didn't downvote, but this is *not* and answer, it is logically equivalent to the questioned code

Comment: @bshirley You are actually not correct. There could theoretically be a case where `nil` is a non-zero value. With current compilers that is not longer possible but in historic systems that was an issue. So, it is indeed very similar but not exactly the same :)